# Changing p2p to create a quark coin mining pool?

Tags: alternatives, quarkcoin

I've been trying to mine some quarkcoins pretty unsuccessfully.

I can only find two pools that are up and neither seem to have returned anything, even after hashing for 24 hours.

I thought perhaps putting a p2p quark pool up would be a good idea, but there are no guides anywhere, obviously it's new'ish. There are a lot of bitcoin p2p guides.

Just wondering if anybody would be able to point me in the right direction of what parts of the bitcoin p2p I'd have to deviate from to get a quarkcoin p2p running?

Comment: @Moschops I mine at 450khash/s and left it all night. I only got 0.02 QRK. Is it that hard to mine QRK? :D

Comment: Can you explain how do you mine directly?

Comment: Brian what is the specialize quark mining edition of ./minerd and where can I find it. Then how do I set it up after that for solo mining?

Comment: Hi Raf,
This area is supposed to be for answers, not follow-up questions. Please ask a new question (any user can!) and refer to this question if it helps to provide context. For more information about the concept of Stackexchange you can refer to [about], or [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the qrk.mime-pool.net for almost a week now and it is working fine:

They have instructions here:

http://qrk.mine-pool.net/start.html

All you need is a wallet address for it to pay into, the password can be whatever you want.  You can monitor payouts to your address from the Payout tab - if it doesn't appear after a few blocks have been  mined something is wrong:

http://qrk.mine-pool.net/index.html#mainnodepayout

Comment: This is not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple'ish.  But a more in-depth one could still be be provided by somebody else, so I wont mark my answer as accepted.

Quark uses 6 hashing functions (blake, bmw, groestl, jh, keccak, skein) and so these need to found and compiled into whatever p2pool is in use.

I've scrapped off the idea of bothering for now, as there's only 10% left of Quarkcoins to mine, probably why there are so few pools about as it is.